# jQuery Regex - Finding All Joined Words

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

### jQuery Regex

```
/((\b([a-zA-Z]{0,15})\b)([^a-z0-9\$_]))/g
```

> **My Attempt So Far:** https://regex101.com/r/d3VUpG/1

Example test string:

```
(options.method==="
|options.method==="
=options.method==="HEAD"
 options.method.options.method==="HEAD"
```

---

### What I'm Trying TO Achieve

Returned as `$1` the value of any connected words such as:

- options.method *- Would = $1*
- options.method.options.method *- Would also = $1*

---

### Question

How can I find all words connected with a dot (.) to then wrap in a span like the below example;

```
.replace(//gi,'<span class="join">$1</span>')
```

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't prefer to `.split` on the period?

Comment: @MrFarberToYou this is being used in my Syntax Highlight script and is wrapping particular sections in `<span>` tags with different classes.

Comment: @TimMarshall - Like this? https://regex101.com/r/MixoAh/1

Comment: Yes @JoshCrozier, that is absolutely what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
/((?:\w+\.)+\w+)/g
```

**Explanation**:

- `(` - Start of capturing group 1

  - `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group

    - `\w+\.` - Match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` characters one or more times followed by a literal `.` character
  - `)+` - End of the non-capturing group; match the group one or more times
  - `\w+` - Match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` characters one or more times
- `)` - End of capturing group 1

So in other words, the non-capturing group, `(?:\w+\.)+`, will match a substring like `option.` one or more times followed by a final `\w+` which will match the final word without a literal `.` character following it. Since there is only one capturing group wrapping everything, you can wrap your `span` tag around the first group, `$1`.

[**Live Example**](https://regex101.com/r/MixoAh/1)

```
string.replace(/((?:\w+\.)+\w+)/g, '<span class="join">$1</span>');
```

---

As mentioned above, `\w` includes underscore, numbers and letters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), so if you only want to match letter characters, then you could swap out `\w` with `[a-z]` and use the case-insensitive flag:

```
/((?:[a-z]+\.)+[a-z]+)/gi
```

Comment: How can I make this also find `.example` as it is just searching for connected, ie; multiple connected by ".".

Comment: @TimMarshall - I'm not sure I understand. If you update [this example](https://regex101.com/r/MixoAh/1), then I can take a look.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Updated [here](https://regex101.com/r/MixoAh/2)

Comment: @TimMarshall - You could use `/(\w*(?:\.\w+)+)/g` -> [updated example](https://regex101.com/r/gqBSsW/1)

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly now! Let me know if you'd prefer me to ask a new question - I'm trying to wrap all within `"` and `'` however I'm having problems with special characters and other languages - [example here](https://regex101.com/r/qyQGpn/1)

Comment: @TimMarshall - You could use a negated character class: `["']([^"'\s\n]+)["']` -> [updated example](https://regex101.com/r/aRG4lh/1)

Comment: Hiya Josh, I know it's been a while and this question is long answered, however I'm just wondering if you can aid regarding the above example in your last reply. In my [updated example](https://regex101.com/r/aRG4lh/5) I'm trying to capture all within comments. Thank you

Comment: @TimMarshall - I suppose `<!--(.*?)-->` would cover most cases. https://regex101.com/r/SgEfi6/1

Comment: @TimMarshall - If you need to cover cases where there are line break, use `<!--([\s\S]*?)-->` - https://regex101.com/r/hCrSs6/1

Comment: Wow, fantastic! Thank you very much once again!